# I have a validation that stops the user navigating to the next window but when all fields are cleared goes to the next window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on a project and I am trying to get my Navigation button to recognise when values already stored are cleared from the clear all fields button made. Its fine when I do not enter any values the first time but if I type them in and store them then clear all fields I press the navigation button then I progress onto the window without entering any details. Is there a way to solve this?

here is my code:
thank you.

```
 private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //clears all fields to start again on enetring your details

        if (SCNResult.Text == String.Empty || Nameresult.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to enter your details and store them before pressing this button");
            return;
        }





        Nameresult.Text = " ";
        box.Text = "";
        namebox.Text = "";
        SCNResult.Text = " ";
        error.Text =  " ";
        //
     }

    /////END OF BUTTON////
    private void comp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This instruction stops the user from continuing if they have not entered their details.




        if (SCNResult.Text == String.Empty || Nameresult.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to enter your details before progressing to the next window");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            computing Nav1 = new computing();
            Nav1.Show();
            this.Close();
        }





        //end of instruction





        //navigates to the next window

        //
    }
```

Comment: You mean it is fine to first time to allow navigation even that assuming the fields are clear and never entered ?

Comment: `Nameresult.Text = " "` is not `string.Empty`, you have one character in that string

Comment: `Nameresult.Text = ""` is `string.Empty`, see the difference?

Comment: You can also set <Nameresult.Text = null> to clear the data and avoid the problem with the space key.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear the fields：

```
Nameresult.Text = " "; //here is the problem
box.Text = "";
namebox.Text = "";
SCNResult.Text = " "; //here is the problem
error.Text =  " ";
```

`" "` is not an empty string, that's why your `if` always return `false`